# Boto3 create_image for AMI creation - Save ONLY the root volume

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm writing a script to create AMI images of instances.

My goal is to ONLY save the root volume.

I'm using boto3.

My test instance has 2x EBS volumes attached. I only want to save the root volume with the AMI.

Here is how my code works:

1. Gather list of instances
2. Analyze each instance to identify only the root device, gather its mapping data
3. Execute boto3's `instance.create_image` to trigger, and passing *ONLY* the `BlockDeviceMappings` for the root device.

**Expected result:** AMI has only the Block Devices I had defined in the `create_image` call.

**Actual result:** AMI has all block devices that were attached to the source instance, regardless of the explicit `BlockDeviceMappings` defined during `create_image`

In my below code, I've written a function that takes **already gathered** source instance data elsewhere. I am ONLY defining the root volume info, the `BlockDeviceMappings` does not declare any of the other devices attached to the source volume.

```
def create_image(inst, instance, inst_dict):
    nowtime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    try:
        image = instance.create_image(
            BlockDeviceMappings=[
                {
                    'DeviceName': inst_dict[inst]['root_dev_name'],
                    'Ebs': {
                        'Encrypted': inst_dict[inst]['vol_encr'],
                        'DeleteOnTermination': inst_dict[inst]['vol_del_rule'],
                        'VolumeSize': inst_dict[inst]['vol_size'],
                        'VolumeType': inst_dict[inst]['root_dev_type']
                    },
                },
            ],
            Description=inst_dict[inst]['inst_name'] + " " + str(nowtime),
            DryRun=False,
            Name=inst_dict[inst]['inst_name'] + " " + str(nowtime),
            NoReboot=True
        )
    except Exception, e:
        logging.error("Failed to create image! Instance: " + inst_dict[inst]['inst_name'])
        return 1
```

I do see that boto3 has a `'NoDevice': 'string'` parameter that can be added to a `BlockDeviceMapping` object. But it's attached to the mapping itself - that confuses me, why would you declare a block device mapping, only to "exclude" it. I'm not sure how or why to use this `NoDevice` value.

**In addition: A specific question:**

- If boto3's `create_image` will create all Block Devices regardless of what's put into the `BlockDeviceMappings`, then why is the `BlockDeviceMappings` even there at all if it just copies the source instance block devices?

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT/Update:**

I've attempted to declare the device mapping for the volume I do not want. Then use the `NoDevice` parameter:

```
    BlockDeviceMappings=[
        {
            'DeviceName': inst_dict[inst]['root_dev_name'],
            'Ebs': {
                'Encrypted': inst_dict[inst]['vol_encr'],
                'DeleteOnTermination': inst_dict[inst]['vol_del_rule'],
                'VolumeSize': inst_dict[inst]['vol_size'],
                'VolumeType': inst_dict[inst]['root_dev_type']
            },
        },
        {
            'DeviceName': '/dev/sdf',
            'Ebs': {
                'Encrypted': True,
                'DeleteOnTermination': False,
                'VolumeSize': 24,
                'VolumeType': 'gp2'
            },
            'NoDevice': '',
        },
    ],
```

The only thing I can see is setting an empty string for the `NoDevice` value. Setting it to a bool or anything else gives an error. 
I've tried 
`'NoDevice': 'true'` and `'NoDevice': 'false'` and `'NoDevice': True` and `'NoDevice': False` and `'NoDevice': '/dev/sdf'` and they all give error. The only thing accepted is `'NoDevice': ''` yet the outcome is the same, both devices are attached to the AMI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.

The trick is to not define anything other than the DeviceName in the mapping if you want to omit it using `NoDevice`

This is working now, adding ANY more information to the mapping will make the `NoDevice` void and ignored.

Hopefully helps someone else in the future:

```
{
    'DeviceName': '/dev/sdf',
    'NoDevice': ''
},
```

Comment: Can you please put the code through which you are creating connection with boto3? @emmdee

Comment: @emmdee its not working, it instead taking AMI of only additional volume not the root volume although I passed root volume ID as DeviceName, but if I pass wrong DeviceName then all the volumes of instance AMI is taken.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make it work properly with this syntax:

```
createImage = client.create_image(
    BlockDeviceMappings=[
        {
            'DeviceName': '/dev/sda1',
            'Ebs': {
                'DeleteOnTermination': True,
                'VolumeSize': 20,
                'VolumeType': 'gp2',
                'Encrypted': False
            },
        'DeviceName': '/dev/xvdf',
            'Ebs':{},
        'NoDevice': '', 
        },
    ],
    Description='AMI created by me',
    InstanceId='i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    Name='Insert the AMI name here',
    NoReboot=False,
    DryRun=False,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following Snippet to take the image of root device only and exclude the rest to devices by addind others as follows:

```
createImage = client.create_image(
    BlockDeviceMappings=[
        {
            'DeviceName': '/dev/sda1',
            'Ebs': {
                'DeleteOnTermination': True,
                'VolumeSize': 20,
                'VolumeType': 'gp2',
                'Encrypted': True
            },

        },
        {
            'DeviceName': '/dev/sdg',
            'Ebs': {},
            'NoDevice': '',

        },
        {
            'DeviceName': '/dev/sdf',
            'Ebs': {},
            'NoDevice': '',
        }
    ],
    Description="Created from Source <InstanceID>"
    InstanceId=i-XXXXXXXXXXX,
    Name="Backup Image"
    NoReboot=True,
    DryRun=False,
)`
```